# Некорректное отображение сайта при увеличении масштаба в браузере

Tags: html, css

При увеличении сайта в браузере на 175% он отображается кривокосо, при уменьшении все отлично. Всю голову сломал, перебрал весь код, но безрезультатно.

Помогите.

Сайт nofreezes.ru

Comment: а зачем увеличивать сайт на 175%???

Comment: Забейте. Это нормально. Так все сайты разваливаются. Всегда верстка проверяется при 100% масштабе. А эти проценты - полный бред.

Answer (score 3):

Ничего страшного нет, это ошибка масштабирования браузера.

Проверять нужно не масштабированием, а сужением окна.

Answer (score 0):

Проверять надо не масштабированием, не сужением экрана, а инструментами отладки. Ctrl+Shift+I, кроме safari(поищите комбинацию клавиш) и IE(f12)